# Display and update user information

Tags: php, html, mysql

I new to PHP and learning to update the user information in the mysql. The problem here is I am not able to display the data on the form nor able to update the user's information. My form seems to be empty instead of having any user information

```
<?php
session_start();
require('config.php');
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $sqlupdate = mysql_query("UPDATE user
                  SET
                    first_Name = '{$_POST['sname']}',
                    password = '{$_POST['spassword']}',
                   WHERE first_Name = '{$_POST['sname']}'
                ");         
}


$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE email='$_SESSION['SESS_USEREMAIL']' and password ='$_SESSION['SESS_USERPASS']' ");
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $first = $record['first_Name'];
    $second = $record['first_Name'];
}
?>

<form method="post" name="studentform" id="student-form" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
        <input name="sname" id="studentname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $first; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input name="spassword" id="studentpassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password" value="<?php echo $second; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" id="ssubmitbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="submit" name="submit">Submit<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil "></button>                                                               
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: stop using `mysql_*`. use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: are you having any results returned from the query? Try to do `var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($sql));` and see whats returned? And use PDO's

Comment: '$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE email='' and password ='' ");' seems to be incorrect, how do i set the email and password matches the one in my current session?

Comment: where you set your `$useremail` and `$userpassword` variable value?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: sorry i have been taught with using mysql. So, I am not familiar with mysqli or pdo

Comment: You are using where condition in update query as  `$_POST['sname']`, In it if user modified the details, the update query won't work. Use unique id for users in table, based on it you will update.

Comment: i have updated the $useremail and $userpassword, it was supposed to be session_username and session_password but i got an error

Comment: Did you print all your SESSION variables?

Comment: so are you suggesting me to edit it like this?
<input name="sname" id="sname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $first; ?>">

Comment: i have set it on another page 

$_SESSION['SESS_USEREMAIL'] = $loginrow['email'];
$_SESSION['SESS_USERPASS'] = $loginrow['password'];

Comment: i need to call the session am i right?

Comment: Print all the session variable in this page. Like `echo <pre>; print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: you have an obvious syntax error here `password = '{$_POST['spassword']}',` and you're not checking for errors at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `SQL` is correct, you could use `PDO's` as followed;

```
<?php 

    $sFirst = '';
    $sLast  = '';

    $conn   = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= :email and password = :password";
    $st     = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue(":email", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->execute();

    if ( $row = $st->fetch() ){
        $sFirst   = $row['first_col_name'];
        $sLast    = $row['seccond_col_name'];
    }
?>
```

You mention setting the values in the query from a session, using the following lines you can assign what ever var to be bound to the query;

```
$st->bindValue(":email", $_SESSION['SESS_USEREMAIL'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(":password", $_SESSION['SESS_USERPASS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

And for your update you could use something like;

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{   
    $sError    = '';
    $sName     = '';
    $sPassword = '';


    // basic error checking

    if(isset($_POST['sname']) && $_POST['sname'] != ''){
        $sName = $_POST['sname'];
    }
    if($sName == '') $sError .= "[MissingName]";

    if(isset($_POST['spassword']) && $_POST['spassword'] != ''){
        $sPassword = $_POST['spassword'];
    }
    if($sPassword == '') $sError .= "[MissingPassword]";

    // if no errors, proceed to update
    if($sError == ''){

        $conn   = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $sql    = "UPDATE user first_name = :firstName, password = :password WHERE first_name :first_name";
        $st     = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $st->bindValue(":firstName", $_POST['sname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue(":password", $_POST['spassword'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
    }
}
```

Before updating I would check/validate the information entered is expected.

I would also use a Unique Identifier when updating to ensure the correct user is updated. For this I normally create a trigger on the table that will generate a short unique code.

Comment: this is something new which I have never learned before. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: no problem. Does it resolve the issue you using the session values in the query?

Comment: @babi how did you get on?]

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$useremail' and password ='$userpassword' ");
```

$record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

instead write `<?php echo $first...` use `<?php echo $redord['firstname`] ;?>
This shoud solve your problem.

P.S

`$useremail` and `$userpassword` must stored in a session (in login page) 
USE:

```
$_SESSION['usermail'] = $usermail;
$_SESSION['userpassword'] = $userpassword;
```

IN QUERY

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$useremail' and password ='$userpassword' ");
```

replace `$usermail` with `$_SESSION['username'];` and `$userpassword` with `$_SESSION['userpassword'];`